# Code not Working : prompting for file in Coursera Assignment

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a code that will get the filename from the user input and print the contents in uppercase format. Below is my code:

```
filename = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(filename)
for fx in fh:
    fy = rstrip()
    print(fy.upper)
```

Comment: Please format the code properly and describe what "not working" means in the question.

Comment: You need to call `fx.rstrip`, not just `rstrip`.

Answer (score 0):

The `upper()` and `rstrip()` functions do not change the string "in place", they return the modified string.

```
filename = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(filename)
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = line.upper()
    print(line)
fh.close()
```

Of course all these can be strung together into a big unreadable line:

```
for line in fh:
    print( line.rstrip().upper() )
```

Comment: Oh for Python3, you want `input()` not `raw_input()` too.  But it's OK for Python 2.